# sql trigger call webservice timeout

Tags: sql, sql-server, web-services, stored-procedures, triggers

I have a sql trigger that calls a web service but because there are several trigger on insert and update the trigger throws a timeout error.

I debugged in Visual Studio and receive always a timeout error when inserting or updating a record.

Below my code

```
ALTER   TRIGGER [dba].[TriggerWebservice] ON [dba].[CallID]
AFTER INSERT
AS

   DECLARE @InternFactureren nvarchar(1)
DECLARE @ID varchar(50)

   --check if something was updated or inserted


   BEGIN
                -- Insert statements for trigger here

         Select @Id=Id From inserted
         EXEC [dba].[usp_CallOphalenVoorDelaware] @Id

END




USE [Helpdesk]
GO
/****** Object:  StoredProcedure [dba].[usp_WebService]    Script Date:          13/06/2015 22:53:15 ******/
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO
ALTER PROCEDURE [dba].[usp_WebService]]
@CallID varchar(38) = NULL

AS

Declare @Object as Int; 
Declare @URL as varchar(255)
Declare @ResponseText as Varchar(8000);

SET @URL = 'http://localhost:4000/Service1.asmx/xxxxxxx?CallID=' +  @CallID + ''

Exec sp_OACreate 'MSXML2.XMLHTTP', @Object OUT;
Exec sp_OAMethod @Object, 'open', NULL, 'get', @URL, 'false';
Exec sp_OAMethod @Object, 'send';
Exec sp_OAMethod @Object, 'responseText', @ResponseText OUTPUT;
EXEC sp_OAGetErrorInfo @Object
Select @ResponseText Resultado;
Exec sp_OADestroy @Object;
```

Comment: If you run the trigger procedure in management studio, how long does the web service call take?  There are a few different areas where you might set a connection timeout.  DB level, connection level, etc.    I also have to say that this design is very prone to errors.  If you are actually considering making web service calls in triggers, at least use service broker, so it's async.  I would take it out of the DB altogether.

Comment: This is a recipe for disaster. Do not do this. Rather look at using service broker and queues to call web services.

Comment: So running it in sql is no good idea? Even with a service broker it's not a great solution ?